# Swift Charts BarMark bar shape when stacked

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

Related to [Swift Charts BarMark bar shape when stacked](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/726275)

I'm trying to apply clip shape on a BarMark with stacked values and the result is that it's applying the shape for each stack item instead for the whole bar.

What I want to achieve:
[image: What I want to achieve]

What I got:
[image]

I've noticed that corner radius is applied to the whole bar but just the top of it:
[image: With corner radius]

Is there any way to get this capsule shape when stacked?
My code is:

```
enum Value: Int, Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case ftb
    case nb
    case remaining

    var color: Color {
        switch self {
        case .ftb:
            return .tint1
        case .nb:
            return .tint2
        case .ramaining:
            return .gray4
        }
    }
}

@ViewBuilder var barChart: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(dates, id: \.self) { date in
                let incomeSummary = incomeSummaries.first(where: { $0.date?.inSameDay(as: date) == true })

                ForEach(Value.allCases, id: \.self) { value in
                    barMark(for: value, date: date, incomeSummary: incomeSummary)
                        .foregroundStyle(value.color)
                }
//                .cornerRadius(20, style: .continuous)
//                .clipShape(Capsule())
            }
        }

        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: dates) { date in
                AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.weekday(), centered: true)
            }
        }
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks { mark in
                AxisValueLabel()
            }
        }
    }

private func barMark(for value: Value, date: Date, incomeSummary: IncomeSummary?) -> BarMark {
        let amount = amount(for: value, in: incomeSummary)

        return BarMark(x: .value("WeekDay",
                                  date, 
                                  unit: .day,
                                  calendar: Calendar.localTime),
                        y: .value("Income", amount))
    }
```

Another issue: I've noticed that when AxisValueLabel is centered the last bar loses its label. Is it a bug?

Comment: I've solved the second issue (last label is hidden) by changing `AxisMarks(values: dates) { date in` to `AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day)) { value in`, no luck yet with the shape.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following...

```swift
Chart(array) { model in
    BarMark
    ...
        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Label", widget.label))
        .clipShape(
            array.last == model 
                ? RoundedCorners([.topLeft, .topRight])
                : Rectangle()
        )
```

But since SwiftUI doesn’t support rounding specific corners, the RoundedCorners would need to be a made-up view...

```swift
struct RoundedCorners: Shape {
    enum CornersToRound { ... }
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path { ... }
}
```